# How can I send keys to a game I am playing,using python?

Tags: python, key

I am playing deus ex human revolution,and there are things you can access with the correct 4 digit code.

I was wondering if you could make a script to brute force it sending keystrokes to the game.
I have tried using send keys but i could not make it work.Any ideas?Thanks.

## **Python:**

**-SendKeys**

This is what I have tried,which I found here:

```
import win32com.client
import time
import SendKeys
import os
from ctypes import *

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
os.startfile('C:\\....exe')
time.sleep( 150 )
shell.SendKeys('1')
```

The way I am trying at first is open the game with the script,put a time delay to load the save game,and I open a terminal to hack it, but the key is not send.

**-pywinauto:**

Using pywinauto I have this:

```
from pywinauto import application
import time

app=application.Application()
app.connect_(title_re = "Deus Ex: Human Revolution - The Missing Link", class_name = "DeusExHRE")
```

Now I am searching which dialogs are available.

## **AutoHotKeys:**

So except from python,I am trying with AutoHotKeys:

This works:

```
SetKeyDelay 180

F12::
     Send {0 down}
     Send {0 up}
     Send {0 down}
     Send {0 up}
     Send {0 down}
     Send {0 up}
     Send {0 down}
     Send {0 up}
     Send {Backspace down}
     Send {Backspace up}
Return
```

The keydelay is the minimum I found that didn't miss any buttons.I am looking for a way to make it faster,maybe by using a different send method.

**Updated:**

-pywinauto
-autohotkeys

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever tried [this](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) ?

Comment: The problem i encounter here is :app.xxxxxx.TypeKeys('C'),i cant find the correct thing to put in the place of xxxx,like notepad on the pywinauto page.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already thought of this but just in case, make sure you try your solution(s) in a couple of places.  IIRC, there's a couple of spots in Deus Ex where you have to discover the code in-game before you can use it, even though the code itself is hard-wired into the game.

What'd be really cool is if you got something to do the hacking mini-games automatically.  :)

Comment: I don't know if just by guessing the code in some instances you can't deactivate the lock,even with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some years late, but answering anyway as other might face the same problem like I did...

In Windows you can use win32api to send keys to the active application, but you have to give it a scan code also to make it work in some types of applications such as games

To send a single key, you must have it's [virtual key code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) that you can get either by
using the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753346/how-to-get-virtual-key-code-of-a-key) or by having a dictionary (that you can easily find done in google or make it yourself)

[MapVirtualKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx)

[keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
import win32api, win32con, time

# in this example i'm using a dictionary (that i called VK_CODE)
# to map the keys to their respective virtual key codes

# Sending the key a
i = 'a'

# send key down event
win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[i], win32api.MapVirtualKey(VK_CODE[i], 0), 0, 0)

# wait for it to get registered. 
# You might need to increase this time for some applications
time.sleep(.05)

# send key up event
win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[i], win32api.MapVirtualKey(VK_CODE[i], 0), win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```