# How to get Virtual-Key-Code of a key

Tags: python, ascii

I am trying to write a function that will receive an ascii key and will convert it to a Virtual-key-code.

Ex:

```
from msvcrt import getch
key= ord(getch()) #getting the ASCII character for a key that was pressed
def(key):
   #converting the key to virtual key code
```

for example:
the ascii code of a is 41. I want the function to receive it and return 0x41-which is the virtual key code of the key.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5):

You can use VkKeyScan from Windows API:

```
from ctypes import windll

def char2key(c):
    # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329(v=vs.85).aspx
    result = windll.User32.VkKeyScanW(ord(unicode(c)))
    shift_state = (result & 0xFF00) >> 8
    vk_key = result & 0xFF

    return vk_key
```

Comment: `VkKeyScan` (or `VkKeyScanEx`) do a great job but they have limits. First `a` (`'\x61'`) and `A` (`'\x41'`) have same scan code (`VK_A`) and differe only by their shift state. Next many non ASCII characters cannot be directly typed from keyboard and return a key code of -1. For example the LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN (`'þ'` or `'\xef'`) cannot be produced on my French keyboard and `VkKeyScan` gives a scan code of -1

Comment: Yes, it seems it works not for all cases. About "First a ('\x61') and A ('\x41') have same scan code (VK_A)" it's normal, you should handle by self shift state.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot - As you include msvcrt.h, the remaining part of the answer assumes that you use a Windows system.

There is no bijection between an ASCII code and a virtual key. For example the character "1" (ascii 0x31) can be produced by the key <kbd>1</kbd> with virtual key code 0x31 or by the numeric keypad key <kbd>num 1</kbd> with virtual key code `VK_NUMPAD1` or 0x61.

The best you can do is to manually build a translation table with the help of the [list of the virtual key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the msdn and choose which key you assume for each ASCII code.

The only easy rules are that the virtual key code for upper case letters (A-Z) and numbers (0-9 but not on the numeric keypad) is the same as the ascii code.

Comment: It's possible by using VkKeyScan from Windows API. See my post